# TFS 2013 Web Portal 'checkout' status

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access, tfs-2013

I have check out my project via VS2013 and form VS2013 explorer, I can see the status of locked by which users. However, I could not see such status via a web portal.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. It is not allowed to check pending changes status on TFS web portal since TFS2012.